# Passing parameter to onshow function in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 pages where I have a listing of elements and I have a modal that displays individual element information for editing purposes. Since I have 3 pages I wanted to create a javascript file that serves the purpose for all instead of hard coding each page individually and for that I need to pass a parameter to my js function. However my function is triggered everytime the modal shows and I don't know where I need to pass the parameter.

This is my js code (on a separate file):

```
$(function(){
$('#myModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show:false,
}).on('show.bs.modal', function(){ //subscribe to show method
    var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('span').data('id'); 
    autoCompletion(getIdFromRow, function(output){          
        var keys = Object.keys(output);
        for (var i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) { 
            document.getElementById(keys[i]).innerHTML = output[keys[i]];
        }   
    });
});
function autoCompletion(rowid,handleData){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: **I Want to get a url here** + "/autocomplete.php", 
        data: { action : 'autocomplete', id : rowid},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var json = data, obj = JSON.parse(json);
            handleData(obj);
        }
    });
}   });
```

And this is the element (same for each table row) that will show the modal

```
<td><a href="#">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" data-toggle="modal" data-id={$building.idbuilding} data-target="#myModal">
</span></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass some parameters from back-end staff to javascript, the easiest way is to create a script in each page with JS var in it :

```
<script>
    var url = 'something-that-is-usefull-for-you';
</script>
<script src='/your-js-common-file-that-will-use-the-var'></script>
```

You can also use a hidden DOM element different on each page :

```
<span id='url' class='hidden' data-url='something-that-is-usefull-for-you'></span>
<script>
    var url = $('#url').data('url');
</script>
```

Comment: Just asked a friend and he said the same. Didn't know you could have multiple data tags in html elements. I'm a noob. Thanks!

Comment: No problem ! You can have as many data-attributes as you want, just remember that it is an HTML5 feature, so you have to set up your application as HTML5 of course (doctype).
http://caniuse.com/dataset